# Is it possible to update a browser based on an event in webserver?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, http

When an event occurs in the webserver, I want the open browser of my application to know about it. The obvious way would be to have a jquery ajax call every minute to the web server to check if anything has changed.

Based on my understanding of how the web works, you cannot get an HTTP response (or an xmlhttp response for ajax calls) without an HTTP (or XMLHTTP ) request originating from the browser. Is that correct?

Comment: It is possible with websockets. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websockets Pusher.com is a paid service that implements it http://pusher.com/ And there are several open source/free servers that you can install. Coldfusion 10 is going to come with one built-in.

Comment: Take into account the compatibility for different browsers http://caniuse.com/websockets As long as he implements a fallback to some other mechanism he could use Websockets.

Comment: wow! Web sockets are really cool. I can barely wait for ie 10. Although every once in a while I look stupid with my questions, the information that I get in return makes it totally worth it. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [nodejs](http://nodejs.org) and the [socket.io](http://socket.io/) module which supports websockets in capable browsers and provides fallback methods for the rest. There are a variety of [free node hosting services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648993/where-can-i-host-a-node-js-app) so no need to sit around waiting for IE 10!

Answer (score 0):

As of now polling from the client is the only way that I think is available.  However, I have heard a rumor that Microsoft is creating a tool with the ability to have an open http session that allows for data to flow back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

[SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) was created for exactly this scenario. It integrates with ASP.NET and uses whichever technology is available (combination of server and client), falling back to long-polling if all else fails.